# How to properly view all object data in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am accessing data from Firebase into a stream builder like below:

```
new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data.documents[0].toString());
        }
)
```

I have tried it with and without `toString()` but no luck. Console always says `Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'`

How to properly view all the key values inside my data object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html, you should call `data` property to get the `Map` object, which has implemented the `toString()` method so it prints itself to readable string.

```
print(snapshot.data.documents[0].data);
print(snapshot.data.documents[0].data.toString()); // or explicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

Or better Still:

```
print('data ${snapshots.data[0].data}');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like VSCode, you could just use the debugger instead.

More info here -> [Flutter Devtools Debugger](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/debugger)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, by this code you are able to traverse through all documents and print values.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) =>
    snapshot.data.documents.forEach(print);
)
```